# How can I change the table width to fit in a two column layout?

Tags: tables, formatting, two-column

I'm using two columns ACM format to write a research. I used the below code to create a table. The issue that the code has been created is too large in width and it's extended to the whole page. I need help to shrunk its width.

```
 \begin{table}[h!]
 \begin{tabular}{lcccc}
 \toprule
 Benchmark & Number of Nodes & Residual Energy of Original & Residual Energy of Modified & Percentage of Residual Energy \% \\ [0.5ex]
 \hline
 1  & 10 & 1.171 J & 1.214 J & 4.3\% \\  
\hline
 2 & 30 & 1.145 J & 1.197 J & 5.2\% \\
 \hline
 3 & 50 & 1.116 J & 1.163 J & 4.7\%  \\
\hline
 4 & 70 & 1.152 J & 1.186 J & 3.4\% \\
 \hline
 5 & 100  & 1.193 J & 1.235 J & 4.15\%  \\
\hline
 Avg &   & 1.1554 J & 1.1989 J & 4.35\% \\
 \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please prepare a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that also includes the documentclass as well as the *relevant*  packages. How to make a table fit into the textwidth entirely depends on the available space which itself is controlled by the documentclass and parameters such as font and margin sized that you probably have changed yourself.

Comment: Apart from my above comment about missing documentclass and packages, you code is not compilable since the `tabular` environment is missing the column declarations. If you try to compile your code as is, you should reveive a bunch of error messages. Please do not ignore them.

Comment: Try with `\begin{table*}...\end{table*}`, note that this was my assumption, able to provide correct suggestion after seeing your complete `MWE`...

Answer (score 3):

By "ACM format", I assume you mean the `acmart` document class. Please advise if this assumption is incorrect.

I suggest you replace the `tabular` environment with a `tabularx` environment to allow automatic line breaking in the header cells. I would also like to suggest that you take information about the units (joule, %) out of the body of the table and into the header instead.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{acmart}
\usepackage{booktabs}

% new code:
\raggedbottom
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,siunitx}
\newcolumntype{Y}[1]{>{\Centering\hspace{0pt}\hsize=#1\hsize}X}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for filler text

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{@{} Y{0.73} Y{0.85} Y{1.09} Y{1.09} Y{1.24} @{}}
% Note: 0.73+0.85+1.09+1.09+1.24 = 5 = # of X-type columns
\toprule
Benchmark & Number of Nodes & 
Residual Energy of Original & 
Residual Energy of Modified & 
Percentage of Residual Energy \\ 
 & & [\,J] & [\,J] & [\%] \\
\midrule
  1 &  10 & 1.171 & 1.214 & 4.3  \\  
  2 &  30 & 1.145 & 1.197 & 5.2  \\
  3 &  50 & 1.116 & 1.163 & 4.7  \\
  4 &  70 & 1.152 & 1.186 & 3.4  \\
  5 & 100 & 1.193 & 1.235 & 4.15 \\
\addlinespace
 Avg&     & 1.1554& 1.1989& 4.35 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\lipsum % filler text
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you could make your table fit into one column of a twocolumn article. I have also removed the `\hline` commands and used `siunitx` in order to improve tha alignment of the numbers in the table. In order to avoid repetition in table, I have placed the units in  the corresponding column headers and in order to sapce space, I added linebreaks using the `\thead` command from the `makecell` package. Lastly, I have alsu used `tabular*` in combination with `\extracolsep` to make sure, the table is exactly as wide as the column of text.

Depending on the document calss you use, the output might differ but you should nevertheless get the general idea of how I ensured your table fits into one column.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
  \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lS[table-format=3] *{2}{S[table-format=1.4]} S[table-format=1.2]}
    \toprule
  & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\thead{Residual Energy}}\\
    \cmidrule{3-5}
{\thead[l]{Bench-\\mark}} 
  & {\thead{No. of\\ Nodes}} 
    & {\thead{Original\\ in \si{\joule}}} 
      & {\thead{Modified\\ in \si{\joule}}}
        & {\thead{Percentage}}\\ 
 \midrule
 1   & 10  & 1.171   & 1.214  & 4.3 \\  
 2   & 30  & 1.145   & 1.197  & 5.2 \\
 3   & 50  & 1.116   & 1.163  & 4.7  \\
 4   & 70  & 1.152   & 1.186  & 3.4 \\
 5   & 100 & 1.193   & 1.235  & 4.15  \\
 Avg &     & 1.1554  & 1.1989 & 4.35 \\
 \bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Quite comprehensive!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tabularx` environment instead of `tabular`. In that case you can, not only set the width of the table to the `textwidth` (can also be achieved by `tabular*`), but also you avoid the overflow of the columns into the margins by using `X` column type which force equal column widths.

Using your posted example, you may get something like this

[image]

With the full minimal code,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
%
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XXXXX}
        \toprule
        Benchmark & Number of Nodes & Residual Energy of Original & Residual Energy of Modified & Percentage of Residual Energy \% \\ [0.5ex]
        \hline
        1  & 10 & 1.171 J & 1.214 J & 4.3\% \\
        \hline
        2 & 30 & 1.145 J & 1.197 J & 5.2\% \\
        \hline
        3 & 50 & 1.116 J & 1.163 J & 4.7\%  \\
        \hline
        4 & 70 & 1.152 J & 1.186 J & 3.4\% \\
        \hline
        5 & 100  & 1.193 J & 1.235 J & 4.15\%  \\
        \hline
        Avg &   & 1.1554 J & 1.1989 J & 4.35\% \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The OP mentioned that the document uses a two column format.

Comment: Yea I noticed later, thanks. The answer however wouldn't be hard to adapt to two columns format, particulary, the OP didn't show issues in knowing how to produce that format.